# iPhone application designing issue when targeting multiple sizes

Tags: ios, naming-conventions, screen-resolution

My core question is about switching of image assets depending upon the screen resolution of the device. 
I know that naming convention is used to display splash screens and app icon. Does it apply on all image assets? Can I design one screen and use proper naming convention to target multiple screen resolution?
If not then what is the optimum solution? Different xibs or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS selects between image resources via filename convention. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW1

You use just one set of xibs, with coordinates in points, not pixels. There are 2 pixels to a point on retina screen iOS devices; 1 pixel per point on lower resolution devices. Almost all of your code can be independent of the high/low resolution difference.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15

Answer (score 0):

in xcode 5+ they've simplified things so you don't have to worry about naming conventions anymore. If you look in the Media.xcassets folder for your new projects, you'll see that you get a "1x" or "2x" slot, standing for the non-retina, retina resolutions respectively. Just drag the image into the slot you want, and it automagically does the rest.

Consequently, you can now get away with not preparing for both resolutions sizes. However best practice is still to keep both (or at least to check against the older models in simulator :).

Comment: I had used media.xcassets for managing image resources but it is not working as expected. when I use iPhone retina 4 inches simulator, images for 4 inches are not loaded. It is also getting images for 3.5inches. Do I need to do any configuration sort of thing or play with code?

Comment: In android there is an option of creating layout files. I believe that  in iPhone there must be something like that. In xib file I make connection to a resource let's say for iPhone 3.5 inches. But How would the OS will sense which image to pick. It's kinda confusing

Comment: Resolution, retina vs non-retina is the issue addressed by the 1x and 2x slots. Are you also suggesting you need different sizes depending on screen height? (i.e. an image that is 3.5" versus one that is 4"). If so, one option is to detect the bounds.height of the screen (4" screens are 568px, 3.5" is 480 -- double for retina of course). In other words, you can put in code in the viewcontroller such that it detects whether you are on the 3/4 or 5, and then loads the desired image accordingly.

Comment: yes you are right I can do that in code. But my question is that as in android we have one xml layout and different folders for images. OS automatically loads images from right folder. Is there any way to implement that in iOS designing phase? Reason is that it is extra work to sense which image to load and which image to not..

Comment: I think I understand your issue. Unfortunately, I don't know of a similar solution in iOS world. iOS developers simply don't deal with as much fragmentation regarding screen-sizes as Android developers do, as the paradigm only has 3.5", 4", and "iPad". If you want a visual layout of 3.5 side-by-side with 4.0, you could theoretically implement multiple viewcontroller SCENES onto the same storyboard, and set the default sizes for uiimageviews respectively. That way, you could still use the same viewcontroller, with different image assets. Multiple storyboards is also an option.